# Why is the compare functionality linked to the (log)visitor id?

Tags: session, log, compare

The first thing I do when starting a project is ask the client if he needs user logs in his website. In technical terms `Mage_Log` module.  In all the cases so far I got the answer:

> No. We will use Google Analytics.

And the next question is "Do you want compare products?". 
I ask these  questions because the log tables tend to become large overtime, and the website gets slow. So I want to avoid fixing speed issues.

The second question I ask is because the compare products section depends on the logs for guest customers. See this in the `addAction` of the product compare controller:

```
 if ($productId
        && (Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId() || Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
    )
```

So if the client want's compare products I cannot disable the logging.
I mean I could search for an extension or build one, but the real question is: **Why is the compare functionality linked to the visitor id? Any good outcome of this?. The guest quotes function nicely by referencing the id of the quote in the session. Why not the same for compare products?**

Comment: Probably because no one would disable any part of Magento, ever project uses every part right ;)

Comment: As long as someone implemented the possibility to disable a core module I don't think this is the reason...but I get the joke :).

Comment: Agreed, though I have seen other parts that do not play nicely after disabling some extensions. In short that is why I do not really get why people love composer and Magento cause to me it feels odd as you cannot reliably split the core modules.

Comment: @DavidManners. Hopefully this will be possible to some degree on 2.0.

Comment: so back to the question what would happen if you disabled the module but then set up your own module with config for `log/visitor` that worked with session information? Never tried it myself

Comment: @DavidManners. I've never tried it myself. I think it's possible but it looks kind of painful. A lot of things need to be overwritten in the compare section.

Comment: apart from the cleaning of the table, which is done on left join anyway, is it not just a lot of `getId()` calls....note I have just searched for `log/visitor` so I am probably missing something here :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it stands I would say that this question is somewhat unanswerable - the reason that it uses the log tables is **because it does.** I really don't think that there was much rationale other than to say that Mage_Log has been present since 0.6B and that early efforts may have been to hook initial functionality on it; after some time the limitations probably came to light and they stopped developing on that idea.

This really can only be answered fully by someone like Boris but I'm fairly confident that the answer to "why did you do it that way" will be "because we did it that way."

Comment: A "because we did it that way" answer is better than a "because ef you" answer. I guess you are right, this is unanswerable. I was hoping for a core developer answer. I will accept this answer mainly because someone realized this is wrong and decided to change it in Magento2. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/536

Comment: You are correct. Original lack of experience with modularity consequences on early stages of development, and more importantly lack of time to revisit and rewrite existing code that already "works"